# How to turn off Mongo (in Replica Set) properly without DB down?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, shutdown

My server set up is like that:

2 x Servers .  The mongoDB has replica set among both servers.  Each is one node.

and then I have my node.js server connect to the MongoDB.

What happen was.. when I kill the secondary server. (shutting down the server).  The MongoDB at primary still up but the Node.js Server had connection issue with MongoDB then.  Even I added the server back, it didn't work.  I use mongoose and connect-mongo .

So, what happened?  how to shut down Mongo node properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your primary is still primary after you take down the secondary, it's a node's driver issue. Anyway you always should have an arbiter with an even number of replica nodes, the "why" is well documented on mongodb's doc.

In case this is a node.js issue, wich version of node-mongodb-native are you using ? I had some different replicaset issues 2 month ago but there have ben fixed with the latest versions. The last replicaset issue of the driver has ben closed the 9th Sept, you shoud giv it a try with the last tagged version ([V0.9.6.18](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/tree/V0.9.6.18) as i'm writing this)

Comment: I think i have the arbiter set up.  My Mongoose, node and mongo is 2-4 subversion behind.  Let me try upgrading it and see if it works. :) thanks.

Comment: the only thing that really needs to be up-to-date in your case is the [node-mongodb-native driver](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/tree/V0.9.6.18), mongodb mongoose and node don't really matter as long as they are quite recent

Comment: The primary won't "still [be] primary" if the other node goes down. It will automatically demote itself. It will still be readable if clients are using `slaveOk` set to true.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a replica set with 2 nodes, when one node goes down the other will demote itself to secondary. If you aren't connecting with `slaveOk` true, then you won't be able to read (and in either case you won't be able to write).

This is a safety measure imposed by MongoDB, which requires that a majority (meaning half plus one) of a replica set be able to see one another in order to ensure that a primary can be safely elected. If a majority cannot be seen, the nodes in the minority cannot know whether the "other half" have elected a primary. Having two primaries at the same time would be Very Bad (TM), as that could lead to conflicting updates.

In situations where you only want to run two nodes, you can also run an arbiter to break ties in the case that one node goes down or becomes otherwise invisible to the replica set. An arbiter is a normal `mongod` process, but does not store any data -- essentially it only participates in elections, and is idle otherwise. In a replica set with 2 "normal" nodes and one arbiter, either one of the two data-holding nodes can go down without losing a majority.

For more, see [the MongoDB documentation on replica sets](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets) and [the documentation on artibers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Adding+an+Arbiter).

Comment: One thing I don't get is.. I kill the secondary mongo, not the primary one.  so, there shouldn't be any voting involve, right?  and why it still breaks?   :)

Comment: Each member of a replica set monitors the others with periodic heartbeat messages -- if at any time the primary member cannot see a majority of the replica set, including itself (note: majority of 2 == 2, so when one is down, by definition there is no majority), it automatically steps down to secondary to avoid conflict scenarios.